# icon displayed as white square

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to display icon on a toolbar but it shows white square. Below is my code. I also tried with Imageview and got the same result.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_myIcon"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is how its displayed

[image]

Comment: is your icon vector drawable?

Comment: no its regular png

Comment: Is your image acessible?

Comment: I tried placing them in mipmap and drawable folders, plus my application is not crushing which would occur if there were not accessible

Comment: Why you are putting android:background="@mipmap/ic_myIcon" try instead android:src="@mipmap/ic_myIcon"

Comment: the same out with src or background

Comment: @Abdurakhmon It could be your image source's issue. Could you please offer a simple sample with the image so that I can reproduce it on my side?

Comment: I took the icon from https://material.io/tools/icons simple png

Comment: @Abdurakhmon Which icon are you using? Can you share a sample using a simple navigation bar with this error icon? We need it to detect which part causes this issue.